# C# DateTime.TryParse date year value swap. 30 Feb 02

Tags: datetime, swap

I have run into a datetime related problem, my program needs to varify whether a user entered date string is valid.

The program is designed to process date value ranges from 01/01/2000 ~ 31/12/2020 and the string format is like "12 Feb 10".

The problem I am facing is, sometimes user enters value like "30 Feb 10" (this value is invalid), which passes format check but DateTime.TryParse will interprate this string as "10/02/1930 12:00:00am".

My solution to this problem is to extract the date, month, year value from the string seperatly and try to recontruct the date string. see the following code.

```
private static void IsValidDateValue(string userInputValue, CustomValidatorExtended custValidator, string errorMessage, ref bool isValid)
    {
        Regex regexValue = new Regex(SHORT_DATE_VALUE);
        if (regexValue.IsMatch(userInputValue))
        {
            Match match = regexValue.Match(userInputValue);
            int dayValue;
            if (!Int32.TryParse(match.Groups["date"].Value, out dayValue))
            {
                custValidator.ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
                isValid = false;
                return;
            }
            int monthValue;
            if (!Int32.TryParse(ConvertMonthNameToNumber(match.Groups["month"].Value).ToString(), out monthValue))
            {
                custValidator.ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
                isValid = false;
                return;
            }
            //this application is designed to handle only from year 2000 ~ 2020 and user only suppose to enter 2 digits for year 
            int yearValue;
            if (!Int32.TryParse("20" + match.Groups["year"].Value, out yearValue))
            {
                custValidator.ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
                isValid = false;
                return;
            }
            DateTime dtParse;
            if (!DateTime.TryParse(yearValue + "-" + monthValue + "-" + dayValue, out dtParse))
            {
                custValidator.ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
                isValid = false;
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            isValid = true;
            return;
        }
    }
```

Is there an easier way using .net framework default method to solve this date year value swap problem ?

Thank & Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DateTime dt = default(DateTime);
string val = "31 Feb 09";
bool valid = DateTime.TryParseExact(val, "d MMM yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
```

Sets `valid` to false, and leaves dt unchanged. With `val` set to `"31 Mar 09"` it sets valid to true and dt contains 2009-03-31T00:00:00 with unspecified timezone. Use different `DateTimeStyles` values to specify local or UTC if needed.

Comment: You don't need the `default(DateTime)` part because when passing variable as `out` the value will be assigned anyway.

Comment: No, you don't. It's a style thing.

Answer (score 2):

This is what you want:

```
DateTime parse = DateTime.ParseExact(parseString, "dd MMM yy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

or to check if it will work:

```
DateTime parse;
DateTime.TryParseExact(parseString, "dd MMM yy" CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out parse);
```